# Only Show an Xfce4 Panel While YouTube Is Launched

Tags: scripts, xubuntu, xfce, panel, youtube

My middle monitor has a panel with a clock at the bottom. When I am in full screen in YouTube, of course the panel with the clock is not seen. I want to create a script that does the following:

I want to launch the following two commands together. Launch YouTube and also set my right right side panel with a clock to be displayed.

```
chromium-browser http://www.youtube.com
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-4/autohide-behavior -s 0
```

When I close the YouTube tab or window then this command would run. It hides the panel with the clock.

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-4/autohide-behavior -s 2
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script works perfect. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check to see if Chromium is already running. 
# If it is not already running then it sleeps longer before recording the PID.
chrom_status=$(ps -e | grep chromium)

# Launch YouTube in Chromium
chromium-browser http://www.youtube.com &

# Display Xfce panel with clock
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-5/autohide-behavior -s 0

# Sleeping is essential here; otherwise the correct PID is not recorded.
# If you run the script and then immediately start opening up other Chromium windows and tabs, then the script will break.
if [ -z "$chrom_status" ]; then
    sleep 20
else
    sleep 5
fi

# Add YouTube PID to variable
ypid=$(ps -e | awk '/chromium/ { print $1 }' | tail -n1)

# Check every two seconds to make sure YouTube is still open
while true; do
    # Without sleep CPU usage is really high.
    sleep 2
    ypid_status=$(ps -e | grep "$ypid")
    if [ -z "$ypid_status" ]; then
        xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-5/autohide-behavior -s 2
        exit 0
    fi
done
```